# Do I have to dispose Realm instances?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, realm

I have a Xamarin Forms application with Realm as database.

Application is downloading data at launch. I compare it against existing data and if particular object exist I update it. If not then I add it. If there are some objects in database that were not dowloanded I remove them.
I'm repeating the process few times when user is navigating through the app. Just to keep everything up to date if possible.

I have subscribed to `ShouldCompactOnLaunch` event and what I observe is that each time I launch an application database is using more and more memory, despite the fact nothing has changed in downloaded data. I'm wondering what is going on? Do I have to dispose each instance manually? In official documentation I found a statement:

`The Realm class implements IDisposable in order to take care of native memory deallocation and file descriptors so instances will be closed automatically when variables go out of scope.`

https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#closing-realm-instances

Disposing each realm is a little tricky for me since I've put accessing realm inside my DataStoreService and I'm accessing data from different threads (each time calling Realm.GetInstance() inside my dataStore). However if manual disposing is mandatory then I will try to refactor my code. If it is not then I'm wondering why each time I launch an app, realm is consuming more and more disk space.

Comment: Hi, if you need to use Realm class instande frequently when app running, not need to relase it manually. Because frequent creation and release will also consume a lot of memory

Answer (score 3):

To directly answer your question, yes, you should dispose of `Realm` instances, especially on background threads.

This is due to the fact that internally a Realm database operates on multiple versions of a Realm, and the bigger the difference between the oldest and the newest version, the more space it will occupy.

Realms on the UI thread will get automatically refreshed to be updated to the latest version, while this does not happen for Realms on background threads, and so they get pinned to an older version until they are closed. For this reason you should manually dispose of Realm instances on background threads as soon as you're done with them.

Unfortunately the .NET documentation of Realm does not give all these details, but you can take a look at the Android one [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#faq-large-realm-file-size) and [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#auto-refresh), as it works in a similar way.

Comment: Your links are dead. Please provide a snip of the documentation relative to C#.

Comment: @HackSlash the links are dead, but the preceding text is actually an explanation of what is presented in the links.