# Realm.io Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, realm

I am having some issues figuring out how the correct way to properly model a many-to-many relationship in my realm, namely around the fact that realm objects are always live.

So the model in question here revolves around two objects: Event and Inventory. An Event can have multiple inventory items assigned to it (think chairs, plates, forks, etc.), and an inventory item can be assigned to multiple events. When we assign it to an event we define how many of said item we want to assign to the event. However this is where the problem arises, since realm objects are always live and the object types are the same, whatever data Events has will affect my inventory data row as well.

Big picture is that I want to show how many items are assigned for each up coming event when I go into my Inventory detail view. So for example I may have 50 total chairs, I've assigned 40 for an event tomorrow, this means I cannot assign another 20 if someone tried to schedule an event that day as well.

My Realm objects look as follows:

```
public class Event : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string EventId { get; set; } 
    [Indexed]
    public string VenueId { get; set; }
    [Indexed]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateOfEventUTC { get; set; }
    public IList<Inventory> Items { get; }
}

public class Inventory : RealmObject
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string InventoryId { get; set; }
        [Indexed]
        public string VenueId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Backlink(nameof(Event.Items))]
        public IQueryable<Event> Events { get; }
    }
```

I then try to do what I want (namely showing how many of the item are assigned for that event) in my VM as so:

```
var item = unitOfWork.InventoryRepository.GetById(inventoryId);
            var nextMonth = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1);
            AssignedEvents = item.Events
                .Where(x => x.DateOfEventUTC >= DateTime.UtcNow && x.DateOfEventUTC <= nextMonth)
                .ToList()
                .Select(x => new AssignedEventModel
                {
                    DateOfEventUTC = x.DateOfEventUTC.DateTime,
                    Name = x.Name,
                    AssignedItems = x.Items.First(z => z.InventoryId == inventoryId).Count
                })
                .ToList();
```

Unfortunately, this is where the problem arises. I tried applying the [Ignored] tag as was recommended in the realm docs so that the item will no longer be persisted. This unfortunately did not solve my issue. I am still new to realm and I am much more familiar with SQL than NoSQL

Comment: I was able to work around this by instead of trying a many-to-many in my realm, I simply query my events table which instead of having an IList of Inventory would instead have a new object in my realm DB which mimicks inventory. Thus Inventory has no visibility into the fact that it is related to multiple event. Seems hacky and an incorrect way to approach this

Comment: The actual issue is not really clear. If your goal is to *show how many items are assigned for each up coming event*, you would use the count of `public IList<Inventory> Items { get; }` within each event. If you want to see if how many chairs you'll need for events on Saturday, query for those events and get the sum of Items.

Comment: So I probably didn't explain it too well, but like the question as a whole is how to properly model a M to M relationship in Realm without it also affecting the actual child component. Ex: Say I have an item with a count of 40, and the event says only 20 are assigned to it of said item, because they're the same object the collection that event has will override the individual item itself in realm

Comment: That's not how Realm works. If you have an event with a list of 20 chairs, there is no effect on the chairs themselves as it's a pointer or reference to each chair. The chairs don't know about the event and the chairs are not *the same object*; they are 20 different chair objects and nothing is overridden. If you then add an inverse relationship to each chair, it's a reference back to the *events* (plural) that chair belongs to. In that case as you add a chair to an event an inverse relationship is auto-created and added to the chair so it will then be aware of the event(s) it belongs to.

Comment: A filter can be applied that returns the count based on the number of items in the list that matches that filter. Assume an event with 20 chairs and 12 tables. Your `IList<Inventory> Items` will contain a total of 32 Inventory items and you can directly filter for the count of those. Generically - something like `numChairsForThisEvent = someEvent.Items.filter("name == 'chair'").count`. That would return a count of 20. You can compare that number to the total number of chairs (from the Inventory objects). Additionally you could get how many chairs are needed in total for upcoming events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggle to see how this could work in SQL either, but I'm not an expert in that so I may miss some details that would allow this to work in the way you structured it.
Coming back to our case: the problem has little to do with Realm being live, but more to do with the way you structured your domain models.
If you use the same "Inventory" model to do 2 things:

1. keep track of the total amount of each item
2. keep track of the amount of each inventory item used in a specific event

you'll have problems with what Count really represents.
Creating a third model would solve all your problems.

1. Inventory        => for the overall amount of an item
2. Event        => representing the event and all its data
3. EventInventory   => representing the amount of an item used in that event

Not having much information about your project and your other models (see AssignedEventModel etc) I could suggest something along these lines

```
class Event : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string EventId { get; set; }

    // ... other fields you need ...

    public DateTimeOffset DateOfEventUTC { get; set; }

    [Backlink(nameof(EventInventory.Event))]
    public IList<EventInventory> Items { get; }
}

class EventInventory : RealmObject
{
    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public Event Event { get; set; }
}

class Inventory : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string InventoryId { get; set; }

    // ... other fields you need ...
    
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    [Backlink(nameof(EventInventory.Inventory))]
    public IQueryable<EventInventory> EventInventories { get; }
}
```

Then in your Inventory's VM

```
var inventory = unitOfWork.InventoryRepository.GetById(inventoryId);
var inUse = inventory.EventInventories
    .Where(x => /*...*/)
    .Sum(x => x.Count);

// your databind count that want to show under Inventory's View
remainingCount = inventory.TotalCount - InUseCount;
```

So basically, now you can calculate how much is left available of a certain InventoryItem in a certain time frame. With these models you should be able to create your `AssignedEventModel` if you need to.
I hope this helps.

On a side node, I noticed that you are using unitOfWork and repository pattern (at least, so it seems). Although it may look like a great idea, it is generally discoraged to be used when working with Realm. This is simply because you are going to miss out on some of the powerful feature of Realm.
You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66356597/realm-how-to-close-and-read/66359903#66359903) in the "Repository" section of the answer.

Comment: You've put a lot of effort into this answer but it's not clear what problem is solves. See my comments to the question. The only thing the OP needs to do is add an inverse relationship from the Inventory object back to the event. Upon doing that, they can get the total Inventory for each event, which events an inventory goes with and how many events an inventory is used on. The purpose as stated in the question was **namely showing how many of the item are assigned for that event** which is easily done with getting the count of the Realm List: `Events.item`. Maybe you can clarify?

Comment: The OP wants to have a centralized amount of available items per type (x amount of chars etc). At the same time he/she wants to assign some of each type to this and that event. These assignments need to be recorded somewhere, that's why s/he needs a third model to record that. Once recorded, s/he can decide if the next event can have up to y chairs based on how many items of x type are taken in that time frame. That is at least what I got from the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. A third model is not needed. It's simply taking the total amount of chairs available from `public int Count { get; set; }` and subtracting the total amount needed, which is the sum from either the events `public IList<Inventory> Items { get; }` property or if there's an inverse relationship added, you're know all of the events the chairs are used on. But, as you pointed out, a third object is an option as well!

Comment: The user showed strong interest in recording the number of each item used per event, so I gave a solution for that. But what you said achieves the same: following all events from an Inventory and scan the list with timeframe filtering. That becomes a bit more involved, namely evaluate the whole event list every time you open an inventory. If the user finds this easy enough to reason about and the performance (maybe with caching on notification changes) is acceptable, I guess it could be fine, too.

Comment: *the number of each item used per event* comes directly from a count of the number of Items in the Items list in the event - as in this pseudo-code `let chairsUsed = event.Items.count`. So it's already stored; remember a List behaves ver similar to an array and has a lot of the features, add, remove and... count!

Comment: No it doesn't not come from even.Items.count because Items is heterogeneous, so it's needed to scan the list to know that. Additionally, I would not personally use an object that has a field count (Inventory) always set to one in some places (event.Items) and with a proper value in some other places; it feels logically wrong. Anyway, I doubt this conversation is adding much value at this point as the OP has already accepted my post and s/he has not shown further doubts in the comments.

Comment: I was speaking at a high level. I am suggesting an alternative to future readers that may want a simpler solution that costs less. A filter can be applied that returns the count based on the number of items in the list that matches that filter. Generically - something like `numChairsForThisEvent = someEvent.Items.filter("name == 'chair'").count`. Your answer is quite fine but in some cases, if there another option that reduces reads, writes and object counts, that can save a considerable amount of money.